# How to handle dynamic conditions in SQL where clause in JdbcClient or JdbcTemplate in 2023?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

Is 'String concat' the only solution as below?

```
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Iterable<User> listByConditions(@RequestParam(required = false) String name,
                                           @RequestParam(required = false) Integer sex) {
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        var sql = """
                SELECT `id`, `name`, `sex`
                FROM `user`
                WHERE 1 = 1
                """;

        if (name != null) {
            sql += " AND `name` = :name ";
            params.addValue("name", name);
        }

        if (sex != null) {
            sql += " AND `sex` = :sex ";
            params.addValue("sex", sex);
        }

        sql += """
                ORDER BY `id`
                """;

        return jdbcClient.sql(sql)
                .param("name", name)
                .param("sex", sex)
                .query(User.class)
                .list();
    }
```

I hate using MyBatis with XML & I love using multiline string with JdbcClient. But I don't know how to handle dynamic conditions where clauses.